# Match/Case used to decide what keys JSON response contains

Tags: python, python-3.10, structural-pattern-matching

I am trying to apply a match/case in my script where I want to do some action based on the JSON response from the API call:

```
response_types =
1. -> {'data': [{'id': 1485037059173588994}]} 
2. -> {'data': [{'media': 1423364523411623943}]}
3. -> {'errors': [{'code': 404}]}
```

1. I need to decide if it's `'data'` or `'errors'`
2. After that if it's `'data'`, I need to decide if there is a key on position `[0]` of the list 
   `'id'` -> [eg. `if 'id' in r['data'][0]:`]
   *or*
   `'media'` -> [eg. `if 'media' in r['data'][0]:`]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `match-case` is pretty straightforward here:

```
match response:
   case {'data': [{'id': _id}]} if _id > 51515: #using a guard, per your comment
       print('response 1', _id)
   case {'data': [{'media': media}, *_]}:
       print('response 2', media)
   case {'errors': [{'code': code}, *_]}:
       print('response 3', code)
```

Note: using a throwaway wildcard `*_` is necessary to ensure that the `case` matches `data` key lists of lengths `>=1`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is the simplest.

```
if 'errors' in response:
    print( "Error", response['errors'][0]['code'] )
elif 'id' in response['data'][0]:
    print( "ID is", response['data'][0]['id'] )
elif 'media' in response['data'][0]:
    print( "Media is", response['data'][0]['media'] )
else:
    print( "Not recognized." )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!:) The things is that when these conditions get nested a lot, it's not very readable, so I was thinking how to do it more organized.
+ when you want to let's say verify that the id is higher than 51515, you first need to verify that key is even there so u don't get an exception.. any better way? dk

Comment: Well, it's up to you to decide how to handle that.  I put "errors" first, because if that one is set, then the rest of the data is probably not meaningful.